# can security patches in magento be seen if they are installed manually?

Tags: security, magento, patch

Someone contacted me telling me that my magento company website was not secure, and they addressed me to http://www.magereport.com/scan/. I told them that the patches were installed manually, which it was what I was told at the time by the developers. I double checked with the developers and they told me that the manually applied patches will not be considered in that url. I however checked this other one https://magento.com/security-patch and says that the website appear to be safe. (including the "bespoke" admin url

Could anyone confirm if it is true that the manually installed patches can't show in those url's?

In one hand I have to trust my developers, and I believe they are saying the truth, but on the other hand I had a couple of people (probably trying to sell something) telling me something different. In the meantime I want to make sure the site is safe, and there is no compromise to our customers details.

What would you recommend as the best plan of action?

Magento version is 1.8.1.0

Many thanks for your honest help!

Comment: I think it might depend on what "manually" means. I don't know how magreport does its check but if it looks for patches applied, rather than testing the code, that might explain the diferences.

Comment: @PedroKTFC, thanks for your comment. Yes you might be right, this is what the developers seem to claim, however as a customer, it leaves you just "trusting" them, rather than "knowing" for sure, which to be honest I do not like... :(

Comment: Ask them to apply the patches "normally". He how pays the piper calls the tune!

Answer (score 2):

i am checking my magento web site at regularly (one a week)

http://mxtoolbox.com/ (ip and domain badlist control)

http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ (malware control)

http://www.unmaskparasites.com/ (malware control)

http://www.magereport.com/ (magento security patch control)

You can trust this web sites. And I think, enough to control these sites

Comment: Many thanks @aligokayduman for your answer. I'll check those too, to see any irregularities. Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.magereport.com/scan/ is very accurate. I would trust your developers.

Comment: many thanks Lisa for your reply. This is the tool were some patches are highlighted as not being done, this is why I was getting nervous. We'll see if someone else has any other comment on the "manual" approach to sorting out patches and if it is true that they are not recognised by this tool.... good day!

Answer (score 1):

Magereport is checking site from front end and cannot see is your php files completly patched. You should check Magefence extension that check your site from backend by scanning php files for each security patch, beside other security features. This is most complete security extension for regular site owners. https://www.extensionsmall.com/mage-fence-security.html

Comment: many thanks Sasha for your suggestion. This module might potentially sort the problem of the insecurity about the whole thing... If I decide to give it a go, I'll let you all know ;0)